# Prove that $\arg$ is a measurable function from $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space and $f=g+ih$ with $g,h$ both being real-valued measurable functions on $X$.

> (1) Prove that $\vert f \vert $is a measurable function.

Since $f,g$ are measurable, we know $f$ is also measurable. But how to show that $\vert f \vert $ is measurable? I can show that $\vert f \vert^2 =f\bar{f}$ is measurable.

> (2)Define $\arg z:=z/\vert z\vert$ if $z\neq0$ and $\arg 0=0$. Prove that $\arg$ is a measurable function from $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Consider $z=re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $(a,b) \to \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$ is continuous, hence Borel measurable. $|f|$ is the composition of this map and $(g,h)$ so it is measurable.

$\{z: arg z \in A\}=\{z \neq 0: \frac z {|z|} \in A\}$ if $0 \notin A$ and $\{z: arg z \in A\}=\{z \neq 0: \frac z {|z|} \in A\} \cup \{0\}$ if $0 \in A$. The map $z \to \frac z {|z|}$ is continuous on  $\mathbb C \setminus  \{0\}$ So $argz $ is measurable.

Comment: So why $z/\vert z\vert $ is measurable?

Comment: @BobOakley: It's continuous.

Comment: @BobOakley I have added one more step to the proof.